# Setting Windows MySQL client default script folder

Tags: mysql, windows

From withing the MySQL client on Windows, how do I set it to point at a particular Windows folder so the file in a SOURCE statement doesn't have to include a path?

Answer (score 1):

A partial workaround I've been using is to change the data directory so it is not so deeply buried (ie. D:\MySQL_Data).  This makes it far easier to enter the path.

Documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir

The downside is that all your data files will now need to live here also.  I'm interested also to see if somebody has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an link(shortcut) to the client and define the working directory(initial directory) to this particular folder you want. I did that and worked fine.